# Any tool to validate the 1000 plus screen fields in web application (.Net)

Tags: coded-ui-tests, gui-testing

**Need to validate 1K+ fields on web application (.net).** which include dropdowns, text fileds in application. here focus is more on weather the data has correctly reflected on the screen!

**Am currently looking for a tool to do the validation.** please help me on this!

thanks in advance!

Comment: Agree with Vi3GameHkr. And I think we definately need more info from the OP: 1K+ screens or 1K+ fields, or both? And what is the data you want to check, always the same type or different on all screens? And where does the data resides: Database, textfiles, pinky-soft-tissue? I also could imagine you can build your own tool as long as you can use COM (-> open browser, extract page from URL, and regex your way around), that is far more faster then a GUI based testing tool.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged coded-ui-tests, have you already considered the technology behind the tag?

From the tag: "Coded UI tests are automated UI tests that can be created with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate or Visual Studio 2010 Premium to test different kinds of user interface: web, WPF, Silverlight and Windows Forms."

With Coded UI Tests, what you want to accomplish shouldn't be too difficult.  For several controls you are able to see their value (which I assume is the data you want to assert).